# how to finish this proof in Coq

Tags: coq

Right now the proof window looks like this:

```
1 subgoals
Case := "WHILE" : String.string
b : bexp
c : com
IHc : forall st' st : state,
      optimize_0plus_com c / st || st' -> c / st || st'
st : state
st' : state
st'' : state
H0 : optimize_0plus_com c / st || st'
IHceval1 : optimize_0plus_com c = optimize_0plus_com (WHILE b DO c END) ->
           (WHILE b DO c END) / st || st'
H : beval st (optimize_0plus_bexp b) = true
Heqloopdef : (WHILE optimize_0plus_bexp b DO optimize_0plus_com c END) =
             optimize_0plus_com (WHILE b DO c END)
H1 : (WHILE optimize_0plus_bexp b DO optimize_0plus_com c END) / st' || st''
IHceval2 : (WHILE optimize_0plus_bexp b DO optimize_0plus_com c END) =
           optimize_0plus_com (WHILE b DO c END) ->
           (WHILE b DO c END) / st' || st''
______________________________________(1/1)
(WHILE b DO c END) / st || st''
```

I feel like this should be provable fairly easily, but I just can't see how to do it. The IHceval hypotheses in the context are close to what I need but they aren't an exact match. Can someone help me out here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I solved it:

```
apply E_WhileLoop with st'.
rewrite <- optimize_0plus_bexp_sound in H.
assumption.
apply IHc.
assumption.
apply IHceval2.
(*Look at the definition below*) reflexivity.
```

`rewrite <- optimize_0plus_bexp_sound in H.` Takes H to `beval st b = true` For why reflexivity worked, here's the definition of optimize_0plus_com:

```
* match c with
  | SKIP => SKIP
  | i ::= a => i ::= optimize_0plus_aexp a
  | c1;; c2 => optimize_0plus_com c1;; optimize_0plus_com c2
  | IFB b THEN c1 ELSE c2 FI =>
      IFB optimize_0plus_bexp b THEN optimize_0plus_com c1
      ELSE optimize_0plus_com c2 FI
  | ********WHILE b DO c0 END =>
      WHILE optimize_0plus_bexp b DO optimize_0plus_com c0 END
```

Comment: Nice. But note that it is the wishes of the authors of Software Foundations that solutions to their exercises not be posted in public forums as they are intended to be assignable as homework in university courses. When you've gotten over the excitement of having solved it, please remove?

Comment: The question is related to Software Foundations, but it's not one of the exercises from the book. Just to be safe though, I've changed the wording of the question to make it less clear what section it's related to.